# Connecting wireless router to wired ADSL modem

Tags: wireless-networking, router, adsl, adsl-router

I'm trying to connect a wireless router to a wired ADSL modem.

Steps followed:

1. Connected wireless router to PC and configured static IP [192.168.1.20], gateway [192.168.1.1]
2. Connected wireless router to ADSL modem via LAN
3. Start both the routers.

I'm able to see my wireless connection but unable to browse any websites.

Comment: What IP address does the ADSL modem have?  Did you disable DHCP on the wireless router?  Did you connect the wireless router to ADSL modem on LAN ports for both?

Comment: The IP Address of the ADSL modem is 192.168.1.1
Yes the DHCP server on the wireless router was disabled & the LAN ports were used for connecting the two.

Comment: When connected to wifi do you get an IP address in 192.168.1.x and can you ping 192.168.1.1, and what DNS are you given?